# Grab original method/column name from Rails alias_attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now, I have some legacy classes with differently-named columns that I've aliased to a new, common name via Rails' alias_attribute, as below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute :id, :UserId
  ...
end

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute :id, :CarId
  ...
end
```

For some logging purposes, I need to access the old column names (eg. CarId and UserId). Is there a general way to access the old name from alias_attribute via its alias? Renaming the old columns is not ideal, since many other parts of the app are still using the old column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alias_attribute` is a very simple method. [All it does](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bd2542b74fe528d95f51d8f3668b0f7d6d8af974/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb) is, well, define aliases.

```
  def alias_attribute(new_name, old_name)
    # The following reader methods use an explicit `self` receiver in order to
    # support aliases that start with an uppercase letter. Otherwise, they would
    # be resolved as constants instead.
    module_eval <<-STR, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
      def #{new_name}; self.#{old_name}; end          # def subject; self.title; end
      def #{new_name}?; self.#{old_name}?; end        # def subject?; self.title?; end
      def #{new_name}=(v); self.#{old_name} = v; end  # def subject=(v); self.title = v; end
    STR
  end
```

So no, there's no way to retrieve the original column name.